# Ubuntu Server Configure Bind9 DNS Server for HTTP request

Tags: domain-name-system, linux-networking, domain, bind, dns-zone

I have configured a Bind9 DNS Server Forward Zone according to the code below. The way is configured, I only can do SSH using the server name <geoportal.geoint.lan>. I tried adding to the code the line <www IN A 192.168.2.210> in order to have the HTTP request working, but it did not work and I would like to know how to amend the code to have the DNS or request geoportal.geoint.lan or [www.geoportal.geoint.lan](http://www.geoportal.geoint.lan) responding on the browser.

```
; BIND data file for local loopback interface 
; 
$TTL    604800
@   IN  SOA ubuntu-server.geoint.lan. admin.ubuntu-server.geoint.lan. (             
           23042705     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry             
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL

; name servers information - NS records  
@                                   IN      NS     ubuntu-server.geoint.lan.  
@                                   IN      NS     db-postgis.geoint.lan.

; name servers - A records  
ubuntu-server                       IN      A      192.168.2.220  
db-postgis                          IN      A      192.168.2.200

; 10.128.0.0/16 - A records  
geoportal                           IN      A      192.168.2.210

; cname record

primario                            IN      CNAME   ubuntu-server.geoint.lan.
secundario                          IN      CNAME   db-postgis.geoint.lan.
geoweb                              IN      CNAME   geoportal.geoint.lan.
```

Comment: DNS is used to look up domain names. It has nothing to do with how that information is used. If it works for ssh it works for http.

Comment: Setting up a `www`  or any  record in your DNS does not enable your server to be able to respond to HTTP requests made from a web browser. For that  your server needs to be configured as web server, in other words your need to install, configure and enable one of the many [web servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software)

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. Based on your explanation, my DNS name geoportal.geoint.lan may conflict with the ones on the web. DNS Server, Bind9 is looking for the DNS on the web, rather than in a local server. Does it make sense?